# How to count running months of a specific year?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently struggling with calculating the running months depending on the year. I have the following table:

```
Received Month    Received Year
Feb               2018
Feb               2018
Mar               2018
...               ...
Nov               2018
Nov               2018
Dec               2018
Dec               2018
Jan               2019
Jan               2019
Feb               2019
```

I was using this formula to count the # of unique months (running months in 1 single cell [C1]);

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/(COUNTIF(KAIZEN_Table[Received Month],KAIZEN_Table[Received Month])))
```

This was working great in 2018, it gave me 11 (Feb - Dec).

I have to add a filter that also checks if the year is 2019. I can't remove 2018 in the table because the operators are still using the 2018 lines. The filter is just here to set a KPI for 2019.

For some reason I can't figure out how to add the year. I tried;

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/(COUNTIFS(KAIZEN_Table[Received Month],KAIZEN_Table[Received Month],KAIZEN_Table[Received Year], "2019")))
```

This is just giving me a 0.

Any suggestions on this? VBA code is also fine.

*Edit: After extensive googling I found a working formula, for whoever might be interested in this.*

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(tbl[Year]=2019,MATCH(tbl[Month],tbl[Month],0)),ROW(tbl[Month])-ROW($L$5)+1),1))
```

*L5 = First row of tbl[Month]*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have my data in A1:B14, the formula I've used is an array one

`=SUM(1/(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$14,$A$1:$A$14,$B$1:$B$14,$B$1:$B$14)))`

however,

`=SUMPRODUCT(1/(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$14,$A$1:$A$14,$B$1:$B$14,$B$1:$B$14)))`

would suffice

To do a particular year, you could do something like this

`=SUM(($B$1:$B$14=2019)*(1/COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$14,$A$1:$A$14,$B$1:$B$14,B1:B14)))`

Comment: I've tried to used this but it won't give me the correct number. Basically I've copied the data in my post (without the ...) and this array formula is giving me a 6 while I need 2 (Jan - Feb 2019). However after extensive googling I did find a working formula. I'll post it in my topic.
Thanks for the help tho!

Comment: Yes I did, I double checked it just now but keep getting a value of 6. Edited A14 to A10, CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER and it keeps giving me 6. Also tried to make it work with a table but it did not work as well.

Comment: Can you post what you did pls.

Comment: I see the last formula now in your comment. The 2 above give 6, probably cause it doesn't filter on a year. Sorry, for the confusion. Last one works like it should!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use a Pivot Table.

On the `Create Pivot Table` dialog, select to `Add this data to the Data Model`

[image]

If you do this, you will note that one of the options in the Value Field Settings will be  `Distinct Count`

Drag `Received Year` to the Rows Column; `Received Month` to the Values column, and select `Distinct Count` for the Value Field Setting

[image]

Comment: Great answer, I would've used this if I could, would be my approach as well. However it has to be a formula, since it needs to refer to a cell (using a shape where this value is displayed). I can refer to the pivot table cell but I honestly don't really like that approach. However, this works just fine as well.